# Insights API returning error for specific post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-insights

I ran into some errors on our test-site today, and started error-testing using the graph explorer.
It seems that i cannot access insights on the latest post from a certain page.
I get the following behaviour in the graph explorer:

1) pageId/posts = Works fine, returning all posts for that page

2) pageId_postId = Works fine, no matter which postId im picking

But when trying

3) pageId_postID/insights that wont work on my **latest** post, returning

```
"error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 1,
    "fbtrace_id": "HxoJW5HIU6k"
 },
```

It does however work on all other posts from that page.
My access token has read_insight permission and i've never ran into this problem before.
The post i cannot access is from yesterday.

Any ideas what might cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After trying with everything - EVERY THING - we discover that the issue is about the Token. We found that the Graph Api Token was working but not our API token.

Using the graph Api, we cleared all the privileges (with the "clear" button) and then we added ALL the available privileges that appear in the popup (in both tabs) and then the graph api started to throw the same error message that appear with the API. Why? I guess the popup where you select the permission are missing some important privileges that you should use to see post insights (This because an hypothetical API upgrade that Facebook does not notify).

But don't worry, the solution is to use the API version 2.3 instead newest. That's all! You can force the API version in your connection settings.

Hope this help you.